# Using /bin/bash -l -c with concatenated commands does not pass environment variables

Tags: bash

I'm trying to execute a series of bash commands using /bin/bash -l -c as follows:

```
/bin/bash -l -c "cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3..."
```

What I notice is that if cmd1 happens to export an environment variable, it is not seen by cmd2 and so on. If I run the same concatenated commands without the /bin/bash -l -c option, it just runs fine.

For example, this does not print the value of MYVAR:

```
$/bin/bash -l -c "export MYVAR="myvar" && echo $MYVAR"
```

whereas, the following works as expected

```
$export MYVAR="myvar" && echo $MYVAR
myvar
```

Can't find why using /bin/bash -l -c won't work here? Or are there any suggestion how to make this work with using /bin/bash -l -c?

Comment: `bash -c` starts a subshell (a child process), once it is killed, the values set are not reflected in the parent shell? Whereas `export MYVAR="myvar" && echo $MYVAR` runs in the same shell

Comment: you are creating a child process  - which has no effect on parent shell,  env is lost when your bash command finishes,  export is only down to child processes.   have a look at "source" command (alias (.) )  wihch runs in the current process

Comment: I'm aware that a subshell will be created, but the second command (after &&) should be executed in the same subshell isn't it? Or every command in the && sequence runs in its owns subshell - I didn't expect that. In my example, both the commands are under the same -c option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

variables are exported for child processes, parent process environment can't be changed by child process so consecutive commands (forking sub processes can't see variables exported from preceeding command), some commands are particular becuase don't fork new process but are run inside current shell process they are builtin commands only builtin commands can change current process environment `export` is a builtin, for more information about builtins `man bash` `/^shell builtin`.

Otherwise expansion is done during command parsing:

```
/bin/bash -l -c "export MYVAR="myvar" && echo $MYVAR"
```

is one command (note the nested quotes are not doing what you expect because are closing and opening quoted string, myvar is not quoted and may be split). So `$MYVAR` is expanded to current value before assigned to `myvar`.

```
export MYVAR="myvar" && echo $MYVAR
```

are two commands and `$MYVAR` because `&&` is bash syntax (not literal like "&&"), is expanded after being assigned.

so that `$` have a literal meaning (not expanded) use single quotes or escape with backslash.

```
/bin/bash -l -c 'export MYVAR="myvar" && echo "$MYVAR"'
```

or

```
/bin/bash -l -c "export MYVAR=\"myvar\" && echo \"\$MYVAR\""
```

Comment: Thanks! This was indeed the issue!